# Why is the first level process init placed in /sbin?

Tags: linux, systemd, init

In Linux essential executables that must be available in single user mode must be placed under /bin. However 'init' is placed in /sbin.
Is this correct?

Comment: For those using the finger (to down-vote) before actually firing up some neurons, this question actually makes sense.
While 'system binaries' aka 'sbin' is a good place for init, its location according to FHS definitions should be 'bin'. And yes, the FHS has and will change thru everybody's efforts to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the first level process init placed in /sbin?

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and [fhs-3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) says that:

> Utilities  used  for  system  administration  (and  other  root-only  commands)  are  stored  in  /sbin,  /usr/sbin, and /usr/local/sbin. /sbin contains binaries essential for booting, restoring, recovering,and/or repairing the system in addition to the binaries in /bin.

As the init process is a binary essential for booting the system, it is natural to place it in `/sbin` directory (if one follows the standard).

> In Linux essential executables that must be available in single user mode must be placed under /bin.

Yes, the standard says so. Still, there is no "must", there is no enforcing. Yes, most distribution packages place essential executable in the `/bin` directory, as this is what standard says they should be placed there, so it's natural to place them there. You can do whatever you want with your system and have your own directory structure that you desire.

> However 'init' is placed in /sbin. Is this correct?

Generally, as a convention, yes. Still, you can pass `init=` kernel command line parameter and basically `init=/place/your/init/binary/anywhere/you/want`. [The first place the kernel searches for a startup process is `/sbin/init`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c#n1396).

And yes, `/sbin` has binaries required for *booting* the system, not necessarily for *administrating* the system when no filesystem are mounted.

> Could it be that init (systemd) is not running in single user mode?

On a system without systemd it is never running.

Comment: Actually Linux FHS specifies 'must' for /bin.
It's a good answer so I'm gonna declare it as answer. Thank you!
On the systems I tested it looks like both /bin and /sbin are located on the same type of filesystem and the same mountpoint. However could not get the single user mode to work from the command line on these (i.e. sudo systemctl rescue) and cannot tell how does the single user mode looks like. Probably have to modify grub2 config files. Won't do that :)

Comment: I meant that there is no enforcing to follow FHS. So you may not follow it/follow a different standard. Ex. systemd has it's own [file-hierarchy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) where `/sbin` (and all the others) is a symlink to `/usr/bin/` and you just "don't care" - everything is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: `modify grub2 config files` Just add `rescue` or `single` kernel command line parameter when booting, on most grub guis, press `e` when booting and edit the line with parameters. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html